# Object of class Convert could not be converted to string amount in words

Tags: php

i used this code to call a function that will convert my number into words words but when i added it on database it gave me error like this : Object of class Convert could not be converted to string did i do wrong thanks for help.

```
class Convert {
    var $words = array();
    var $places = array();
    var $amount_in_words;
    var $decimal;
    var $decimal_len;

    function __construct($amount, $currency = "Pesos") {
        $this->assign();

        $temp = (string)$amount;
        $pos = strpos($temp,".");
        if ($pos) {
            $temp = substr($temp,0,$pos);
            $this->decimal = strstr((string)$amount,".");
            $this->decimal_len = strlen($this->decimal) - 2;
            $this->decimal = substr($this->decimal,1,$this->decimal_len+1);
        }
        $len = strlen($temp)-1;
        $ctr = 0;
        $arr = array();
        while ($len >= 0) {
            if ($len >= 2) {
                $arr[$ctr++] = substr($temp, $len-2, 3);
                $len -= 3;
            } else {
                $arr[$ctr++] = substr($temp,0,$len+1);
                $len = -1;
            }
        }

        $str = "";
        for ($i=count($arr)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
            $figure = $arr[$i];
            $sub = array(); $temp="";
            for ($y=0; $y<strlen(trim($figure)); $y++) {
                $sub[$y] = substr($figure,$y,1);
            }
            $len = count($sub);
            if ($len==3) {
                if ($sub[0]!="0") {
                    $temp .= ((strlen($str)>0)?" ":"") . trim($this->words[$sub[0]]) . " Hundred";
                }
                $temp .= $this->processTen($sub[1], $sub[2]);
            } elseif ($len==2) {
                $temp .= $this->processTen($sub[0], $sub[1]);
            } else {
                $temp .= $words[$sub[0]];
            }
            if (strlen($temp)>0) {
                $str .= $temp . $this->places[$i];
            }
        }
        $str .= " " . $currency;
        if ($this->decimal_len>0) {
            $str .= " And " . $this->decimal .  " Cents";
        }
        $this->amount_in_words = $str;
    }

    function denominator($x) {
        $temp = "1";
        for ($i=1; $i<=$x; $i++) {
            $temp .= "0";
        }
        return $temp;
    }

    function display() {
        echo $this->amount_in_words;
    }

    function processTen($sub1, $sub2) {
        if ($sub1=="0") {
            if ($sub2=="0") {
                return "";
            } else {
                return $this->words[$sub2];
            }
        } elseif ($sub1!="1") {
            if ($sub2!="0") {
                return $this->words[$sub1."0"] . $this->words[$sub2];
            } else {
                return $this->words[$sub1 . $sub2];
            }
        } else {
            if ($sub2=="0") {
                return $this->words["10"];
            } else {
                return $this->words[$sub1 . $sub2];
            }
        }
    }

    function assign() {
        $this->words["1"] = " One";             $this->words["2"] = " Two";
        $this->words["3"] = " Three";       $this->words["4"] = " Four";
        $this->words["5"] = " Five";            $this->words["6"] = " Six";
        $this->words["7"] = " Seven";           $this->words["8"] = " Eight";
        $this->words["9"] = " Nine";

        $this->words["10"] = " Ten";            $this->words["11"] = " Eleven";
        $this->words["12"] = " Twelve";     $this->words["13"] = " Thirten";
        $this->words["14"] = " Fourten";        $this->words["15"] = " Fiften";
        $this->words["16"] = " Sixten";     $this->words["17"] = " Seventen";
        $this->words["18"] = " Eighten";        $this->words["19"] = " Nineten";

        $this->words["20"] = " Twenty";     $this->words["30"] = " Thirty";
        $this->words["40"] = " Forty";      $this->words["50"] = " Fifty";
        $this->words["60"] = " Sixty";      $this->words["70"] = " Seventy";
        $this->words["80"] = " Eighty";     $this->words["90"] = " Ninety";

        $this->places[0] = "";                  $this->places[1] = " Thousand";
        $this->places[2] = " Million";      $this->places[3] = " Billion";
        $this->places[4] = " Thrillion";
    }
}






$convert = new Convert($Amount);
            $convert->display(); echo " Only";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO vouchercheck (Payee,CheckNo,Date1,AmountinWord,Amount) VALUES ('$Payee','$CheckNo','$Date','".$convert."','$Amount')";
```

Comment: what did you send in for `$Amount`?

Comment: numbers example : 300

Comment: can you hard code a string and confirm the `sql` statement works?

Comment: You're concatenating the `$convert` object in your query. But it isn't an string, it's an object. Maybe you should pass  `$convert->display()`, assuming it does what I think it does.

Comment: I actually think `$convert->display()` will echo instead of returning. Change the function (if you can) to make it return a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the code for your Convert class.

With that said, the obvious error being returned is that you are trying to concatenate an "object" (your $convert variable is an object of the Convert class) with a string.

Your Convert class should have a method like "display" that returns the "AmountinWord" string you are expecting.

Display might be that class method, although you should NOT be using "echo" in that method, but rather you should be using return $somevalue;

In that case you would want:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vouchercheck (Payee,CheckNo,Date1,AmountinWord,Amount) VALUES ('$Payee','$CheckNo','$Date','" . $convert->display() . "','$Amount')";
```

An alternative method to use in your Convert class, is to define the "magic method"  __toString.  This comes from the Java world, where classes often have a toString method defined that will render a string compatible version of an object.  So in your class you would want something like:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->amount_in_words;
}
```

If you have this method, then you would be able to use the existing code you had:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vouchercheck (Payee,CheckNo,Date1,AmountinWord,Amount) VALUES ('$Payee','$CheckNo','$Date','".$convert."','$Amount')";
```

Full Class code will now be:

class Convert {
    var $words = array();
    var $places = array();
    var $amount_in_words;
    var $decimal;
    var $decimal_len;

```
function __construct($amount, $currency = "Pesos") {
    $this->assign();

    $temp = (string)$amount;
    $pos = strpos($temp,".");
    if ($pos) {
        $temp = substr($temp,0,$pos);
        $this->decimal = strstr((string)$amount,".");
        $this->decimal_len = strlen($this->decimal) - 2;
        $this->decimal = substr($this->decimal,1,$this->decimal_len+1);
    }
    $len = strlen($temp)-1;
    $ctr = 0;
    $arr = array();
    while ($len >= 0) {
        if ($len >= 2) {
            $arr[$ctr++] = substr($temp, $len-2, 3);
            $len -= 3;
        } else {
            $arr[$ctr++] = substr($temp,0,$len+1);
            $len = -1;
        }
    }

    $str = "";
    for ($i=count($arr)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        $figure = $arr[$i];
        $sub = array(); $temp="";
        for ($y=0; $y<strlen(trim($figure)); $y++) {
            $sub[$y] = substr($figure,$y,1);
        }
        $len = count($sub);
        if ($len==3) {
            if ($sub[0]!="0") {
                $temp .= ((strlen($str)>0)?" ":"") . trim($this->words[$sub[0]]) . " Hundred";
            }
            $temp .= $this->processTen($sub[1], $sub[2]);
        } elseif ($len==2) {
            $temp .= $this->processTen($sub[0], $sub[1]);
        } else {
            $temp .= $words[$sub[0]];
        }
        if (strlen($temp)>0) {
            $str .= $temp . $this->places[$i];
        }
    }
    $str .= " " . $currency;
    if ($this->decimal_len>0) {
        $str .= " And " . $this->decimal .  " Cents";
    }
    $this->amount_in_words = $str;
}

function __toString() {
    return $this->amount_in_words;
}

function denominator($x) {
    $temp = "1";
    for ($i=1; $i<=$x; $i++) {
        $temp .= "0";
    }
    return $temp;
}

function display() {
    echo $this->amount_in_words;
}

function processTen($sub1, $sub2) {
    if ($sub1=="0") {
        if ($sub2=="0") {
            return "";
        } else {
            return $this->words[$sub2];
        }
    } elseif ($sub1!="1") {
        if ($sub2!="0") {
            return $this->words[$sub1."0"] . $this->words[$sub2];
        } else {
            return $this->words[$sub1 . $sub2];
        }
    } else {
        if ($sub2=="0") {
            return $this->words["10"];
        } else {
            return $this->words[$sub1 . $sub2];
        }
    }
}

function assign() {
    $this->words["1"] = " One";             $this->words["2"] = " Two";
    $this->words["3"] = " Three";       $this->words["4"] = " Four";
    $this->words["5"] = " Five";            $this->words["6"] = " Six";
    $this->words["7"] = " Seven";           $this->words["8"] = " Eight";
    $this->words["9"] = " Nine";

    $this->words["10"] = " Ten";            $this->words["11"] = " Eleven";
    $this->words["12"] = " Twelve";     $this->words["13"] = " Thirten";
    $this->words["14"] = " Fourten";        $this->words["15"] = " Fiften";
    $this->words["16"] = " Sixten";     $this->words["17"] = " Seventen";
    $this->words["18"] = " Eighten";        $this->words["19"] = " Nineten";

    $this->words["20"] = " Twenty";     $this->words["30"] = " Thirty";
    $this->words["40"] = " Forty";      $this->words["50"] = " Fifty";
    $this->words["60"] = " Sixty";      $this->words["70"] = " Seventy";
    $this->words["80"] = " Eighty";     $this->words["90"] = " Ninety";

    $this->places[0] = "";                  $this->places[1] = " Thousand";
    $this->places[2] = " Million";      $this->places[3] = " Billion";
    $this->places[4] = " Thrillion";
}
```

}

Comment: not working :( no error but the $convert->display() displaying empty but when i echo it has a value

Comment: Again, we can only guess when you haven't provided the relevant Convert class code.

Comment: see my question now

Comment: Yes, I already provided you 2 answers, either of which will fix your issue.  Probably the best answer is to add the __toString() method to your class.